# On the definition of a normal crossing divisor

Tags: algebraic-geometry, manifolds, foliations

I'm reading a material that states:

*Definition*: Let F be a foliation on a analytical manifold N. A normal crossing divisor on N is a collection of submanifolds $E$ of $N$ such that for every point $p\in E$ there is a coordinate system for $N$ $(x_1,...,x_n)$ such that
$$
E=(\Pi _{i\in A}x_i=0)\text{ locally in $p$.}
$$
for $A\subset\{1,...,n\}$.
Can somebody explain what does this product means, geometrically? Does this mean that at least one of the coordinates is set as zero?

Does this also means that $E$ is a algebraic manifold? In this case, an *irreductible component* of $E$ is the zero locus of the irreductible components of $E$?

Comment: This means that locally near every point, there's an (analytic) change of coordinates after which E looks like a union of the coordinate hyperplanes. Note that you don't specify how many coordinate hyperplanes are meeting at a point: for a general point $p \in E$, there will be just one, but there could be as many as $n$. (No more, though!) This condition makes it very easy to deal with the singularities of E, say by blowing up.

Comment: So for example in 2 dimensions, a normal crossing divisor locally looks like a line at almost all points, and possibly like a "cross" at finitely many points. You can try to give a similar description in 3 dimensions.

Comment: By the way, I don't really understand the last question. A divisor like this certainly need not be a manifold: at any point at which the local equation involves more than one $x_i$, the divisor $E$ will be singular. It's not even true that each component of $E$ must be nonsingular: for example, a nodal plane curve is a perfectly good normal crossing divisor.

Comment: Ok, the last question was really nonsense, I'm erasing it. But I still don't understand the concept of normal crossing. We could focus in the case that the dimension of $N$ is two, which is the onethat I'm working with now.

Comment: Of course, if you don't mind explaining it again for this empty-brained student :P

Comment: OK, so let's try to break down what the definition says in dim 2. Every point $p$ on $E$ has a neighbourhood $N$ with local coordinates $(x,y)$ such that $E \cap N$ is defined (maybe after swapping $x$ and $y$) by either the equation $x=0$ or the equation $xy=0$. The first equation defines a subset in $N$ that looks like a line, the second one defines a subset that looks like a "cross". Does that help? If not, let me know what I am being unclear about.

Comment: (Oh, I just noticed that $N$ in your question means the whole manifold --- change $N$ to $U$ in my previous comment.)

Comment: I think you made it perfectly clear. Now, to another question, if I'm not abusing of your good will; the points in $E$ such that $xy=0$ (now, considering U locally as $\mathbb{C}^2$ are those where $E$ has an auto-intersection? Or am I talking nonsense?

Comment: (The software is yelling at me, so this should be the last comment...) One needs to be a little careful. In this local neighbourhood $U$, the points where $xy=0$ are _all_ the point of $E$. The (unique) point where $E$ intersects itself is the point where $x=0$ _and_ $y=0$. Be sure to check you understand why these aren't the same!